# How to I add the total of a particular column in a list view and add it into a text box?

Tags: vb.net, listview

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    If txtCode.Text = "" Or txtName.Text = "" Or txtUnit.Text = "" Or txtPrice.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill in all fields")
    Else

        Dim str(3) As String
        Dim itm As ListViewItem


        str(0) = LSet(txtName.Text, 8)
        str(1) = LSet(txtCode.Text, 3)
        str(2) = LSet(txtUnit.Text, 6)
        str(3) = LSet(txtPrice.Text, 20)

        itm = New ListViewItem(str)

        ListView1.Items.Add(itm)

        lblTotalItems.Text = ListView1.Items.Count


        txtCode.Text = ""
        txtName.Text = ""
        txtUnit.Text = ""
        txtPrice.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

I currently have this code for my list view, with more code in my global variables, I'm wanting to add up one column and place them in the Total text box, I know you have to loop through it and add them but i'm not sure how.

Here is the image for the form
[image]

Comment: Your business logic should be performed off of the UI. See, your number is entered as a string to a textbox, then put in a listview, then converted from a string to a number, all on the UI. If you handle the number validation when it's entered (you should either way), then you can store it in an object, and then *display* the results on the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the type of loop you could use.

```
    Const col As Integer = 3 'this adds the price column
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    Dim lvsi As ListViewSubItem

    For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        lvsi = ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(col)
        total += Integer.Parse(lvsi.Text)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot simple than a **ListView** use a **DataGridView**
Just initialize it on Form.Load() with:

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name")
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Code", "Code")
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Unit", "Unit")
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Price", "Price")
DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
```

Then on Add button:

```
If txtCode.Text = "" Or txtName.Text = "" Or txtUnit.Text = "" Or txtPrice.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please fill in all fields")
Else
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtName.Text, txtCode.Text, txtUnit.Value, Decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * txtUnit.Value)
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End If
```

Here I did the Price column = the Unit times the price you entered.
I also handled decimals partly but you would need to check that price is **2.00 and not 2**

Then for total button:

```
Dim MyTotal As Decimal = 0.00
'For each row in the gridd
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    'invcrement total with column 3 equal to the price (index start = 0)
    MyTotal = MyTotal + Decimal.Parse(row.Cells(3).Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Next
txtTotal.Text = MyTotal
```

I'll let you figure out the rest